# Sql Data Type for Primary Key - SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, types

Which sql data type should we use for number bases primary key:

1. int
2. bigint
3. numeric
4. float

Comment: It depends! In what sort of situation?  More info required please...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Generally, `int`.

`bigint` if you think you'll have more rows than there are atoms in the universe.

`uniqueidentifier` is useful if you need *globally* unique keys (keys that are guaranteed to be unique across all tables in your schema, maybe even universally unique (I don't remember))

The other two I wouldn't use they're not integral types (they have fractions, which just don't make a lot of sense as keys)

Comment: If you choose a uniqueidentifier, then consider making it a NONCLUSTERED primary key, otherwise inserts can have performance issues.

Comment: int is limited 'only' around 2 billions.
I already reached this limit with some logging features ;)

Comment: @KenGentle - good answer, but bigint is still useful if you have greater than 4,294,967,296 rows. `more rows than there are atoms in the universe` refers to the *MAX* for uint64, but sometimes you just need to use bigint to go past max for uint32. Two examples you might come across in practice: a data-record for every human alive exceeds 32-bit limit; similarly translating an IPv6 address into a uint requires 48 bits (i like using the other 16 for flags or sometimes a low-res timestamp ;] )

Comment: Not that this is the salient point of Ken's very useful answer, but `bigint`'s 64-bit max value is far from the estimated number of atoms in the universe, -- around 10^80 -- which would not fit in even a 256-bit integer. :)

Comment: @KenGentle -  Hahaha, +1 for rows more than atoms in universe!!

Comment: If you set the identity seed to the lowest negative number for the data type then you double the total number of values that can be stored in the column.

Answer (score 25):

You really need to keep two separate issues apart:

1) the *primary key* is a logical construct - one of the key candidates that uniquely and reliably identifies a row in your table. This can be anything, really - an INT, a GUID, a string - pick what makes most sense for your scenario.

2) the *clustering key* (the column or columns that define the "clustered index" on the table) - this is a *physical* storage-related thing, and here, a small, stable, ever-increasing data type is your best pick - INT or BIGINT as your default option.

By default, the primary key on a SQL Server table is also used as the clustering key - but that doesn't need to be that way! I've personally seems massive performance gains over time when breaking up the previous GUID-based Primary Clustered Key into two separate key - the primary (logical) key on the GUID, and the clustering (ordering) key on a separate INT IDENTITY(1,1) column.

The index fragmentation was down to minimal levels, and thus the index seek performance was was up - highly recommended !

Marc

Comment: Yeah totally agreed Marc - just it's pretty rare for average folk to see beyond the diagramming tools, and it's oh so easy to to right-click, set PK...

Answer (score 3):

One huge reason to not use GUIDs for PKs is their terrible fill ratio for index pages - such misuse can dramatically increase your I/O performance costs.  GUIDs should be left as AK's and instead drive queries with int-derived PK's wherever possible.

Comment: That really is a bit inaccurate - GUID as a PK is okay- GUID as the CLUSTERING KEY is a desaster. The PK per se has no effect on the physical data organisation - that's the clustering key's job :)

Answer (score 0):

for 32-bit processors, an int is likely to be the most efficient size for processing.

Comment: The word boundaries are less relevant than the space occupied switching up from Int to BigInt - unless you expect a row count in the billions, save the row bytes and spend them elsewhere.  I/O cost is several orders more expensive than memory access.

Comment: Agreed, I'm just adding another reason to use int.

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned int` of whichever size that meets your particular needs

Comment: Except SQL server doesn't have unsigned datatypes.