# ASP.NET MVC Model id type --- best practices

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

Simple question. I have several different models stored in SQL databases. A Table of images records with byte data, large multi-field user data table, ect. All of these models require primary keys. Most beginner tutorials show usage of int for ids. Is this standard and professional. I find it odd to start use int since is variable in length and starts with 1 :S

Sorry for the amateur question, but I couldn't find any adequate materials on the subject via google.

Comment: What makes you say that int is of "variable length and start with 1" ?
Link to somehow related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255569/sql-data-type-for-primary-key-sql-server

Comment: SQL Server's `INT IDENTITY` columns default to `1` seed and `1` increment. But you can [change the definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(v=sql.80).aspx) by declaring your column `Id INT IDENTITY(seed, inc)`

Comment: kivin, thanks I remember seeded SQL before but didn't know how to do it from the model.
darkey what i meant about variable length is the number of digits. I like seeing Id's like 0001, 0234, ect or like a guid is guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing implicitly unprofessional about the use of `INT` or any other [integral data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) as a primary key or identity column. It just depends on your business needs. In the interest of keeping programming [as simple as possible](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/2927.html), the `INT` data type is a fine choice for many business needs:

- It is capable of representing about 2.1 billion unique records.
- It consumes minimal hard disk space in modern hardware.
- It is fast for `SELECT`s and `UPDATE`s.
- It is fairly ease to refactor up to a larger integral if the number of records threatens to exceed the limits. `BIGINT` can address more records than you can put in your database. Seriously.

One reason you might *not* want to use an integral primary key:

- You might use a `Guid` (or `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` in SQL Server terms) for global uniqueness. In other words, if you migrate your data to another location, the primary key should still be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `int` is industry standard.

Even beyond databases, I rarely see C# code with `uint` or any of the other variants for representing whole numbers. Occasionally `byte` is used in arrays. `long` is used when `int` may not be big enough to cover all possibilities.

One advantage of always using `int` is that you can pass `id` variables around without having to worry about casting between the different integer types.

Answer (score 0):

This is 100% ok, and widely used. Some use `long`s for primary keys, since their max value is bigger. Though, not necessary in most occasions.

Answer (score 0):

`Guid` type is also used sometimes as an ID. It has some benefits, like fixed length, global uniqueness and unpredictability. And some issues like lower search performance and it's hard to remember.