# Single primary key with BIGINT vs compound primary key including foreign keys

Tags: database-schema, ddl

I have a parent-child relationship between two tables

```
CREATE TABLE symbol (
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE time_series (
    id INT,
    actual_date DATE,
    symbol_id INT,
    data1 FLOAT,
    data2 VARCHAR(50)
)
```

`time_series` has a `symbol_id` foreign key to `symbol`, and a unique date column, `actual_date`.

Now at the moment `time_series` has an `INT` primary key column but I have been blitzing the app with load tests and almost reached the limit of available primary keys.

It seems my alternatives are either to increase the size of the primary key column to `BIGINT`, or to drop the id column and create the primary key on `symbol_id` and `actual_date`.

I've read that a `BIGINT` column primary key is slower than an `INT` column, and performance is a factor in my decision-making. How much of a hit would I take using `BIGINT`? Does a compound primary key also perform slower?

In terms of other factors, this time_series table will never have any child tables, so there would be no inconvenient compound foreign keys.

Read this already: [Sql Data Type for Primary Key - SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255569/sql-data-type-for-primary-key-sql-server)

Comment: I think this is a good tip for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376610/bigint-mysql-performance-compared-to-int

Comment: there is certainly a lot of info there but the comparison between single BIGINT col primary key and compound primary key is what really interests me. Although there is the suggestion of `MEDIUMINT` or `UNSIGNED INT`, but not sure if we are going to use MySQL even (currently on MSSQL, probably moving to MySQL or Postgres)

Comment: lacking any sage advice from SQL and domain model gurus, I have decided against `BIGINT` and I'm going with the compound primary key for the child table. My decision hinged around how the web service API using `Spring Data Rest` would handle the time_series entities when there is a compound primary key, but since the time_series entities will only ever be accessed as a collection, then the primary key will never appear on the API (famous last words)